# There is an option to create 3 files with XIB in Xcode 4.3?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib, xcode4.3

I've noticed that there is no option to choose "With XIB for user interface" in Xcode 4.3 when you create a new file.

What i do is, i created a new file with h and m and after that i add a new View file with xib extension but he not recognized the header file.

Where is the old option to create a 3 files in Xcode 4.3 (h, m and xib) ? is exist there?

Thanks.

Comment: have you set the className correctly in inspector window for xib file?

Comment: Yeah thats odd, the only new file that lets you do this now is Objective-C Class subclass of UIViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me for both iOS and OS X projects.

Under iOS you must use `UIViewController`* as the super class. That is in the field labeled "Subclass of" input `UIViewController`. And the same goes for OS X but there "Subclass of" should be `NSViewController`**.

*: `UITableViewController` and similar view controllers in UIKit should also work.

**: `NSTableViewController` and similar view controllers in Cocoa should also work.

Answer (score 1):

To get your view loaded from xib do the following:

1. Create h+m file for it (Command+N -> [Cocoa Touch|Cocoa] -> Objective-C class)
2. Create xib file (Command+N -> User Interface -> View)
3. Open xib in Interface Builder, select only one view exist there and insert your class name in Custom Class field (located in right sidebar, 3rd tab)

After loading view from xib you will get the view you wanted

```
+ (id) instanceWithXib: (NSString*) nibName
{
NSArray* elements = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: nibName owner: self options: nil];
for (NSObject* object in elements) 
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass: self.class]) 
        return object;
}

return nil;
}
```